# How to add my own Magento 2 WSDL file

Tags: magento2, api, wsdl

Magento 1.9 I used the WSDL

> https://github.com/marouanbmm/magento-Apis/blob/master/code/local/Tecnifibre/SerienFlow/etc/wsdl.xml

file as part of my development `Delphi win 32` to have access to the functions, arrays, objects etc... This was very helpful.

Actually I need to customize this module to use into `Magento 2`, so I must
use wsdl file in `Magento 2`.

Can anyone enlighten me ?

Answer (score 0):

I give you an exemple to how to use your custom `SOAP` wsdl.

You create a function in your block module, then you call this function where you want.

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block;

class wsdl extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{
    const USER = "User here";
    const PASSWORD = "pass here";

    protected $_customerSession;
    protected $_soapClientFactory;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_logger;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Webapi\Soap\ClientFactory $soapClientFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        $this->_soapClientFactory = $soapClientFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_logger = $logger;
    }


    /**
     * @object call custom wsdl
     */
    public function somefunctionName($param1)
    {
        ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");

        $credentials = array('login' => self::USER, 'password' => self::PASSWORD);
        $options = array("trace" => 1, "exception" => 0, 'encoding' => 'UTF-8');
        $ServiceWeb_path = "ws/wsdl_path.xml";
        $url = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl().$ServiceWeb_path;
        $soap = $this->_soapClientFactory->create($url, $credentials);

        //Debug
        //\Zend_Debug::dump($soap);
        //\Zend_Debug::dump($soap->__getFunctions());
        //\Zend_Debug::dump($soap->__getTypes());
        try {
            $result = $soap->__soapCall("wsdl_method", array("parameters" => array("args0" => array("wsdl_param1" => $param1))));
            return $result;
            //\Zend_Debug::dump( "Request :\n".htmlspecialchars($soap->__getLastRequest()));
            //\Zend_Debug::dump(htmlspecialchars($soap->__getLastResponse()));

        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->_logger->critical("SOAP ERROR : ".$e->getMessage());
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

**Info :** Your `file.wsdl` you put It in root project `magentoProject/ws/file.wsdl`, It is not a good idea to put here but, you can moove it in your module to do thigs better.